# Change directory problem in ksh

Tags: cd-command, ksh

I work with Ubuntu 18.04.3

My current directory is `/home/hans/bin`, The directory `/home/hans/.sshz` also exist. My shell is "ksh."

The command `cd ../.ssh` give the output.

```
ksh cd: /home/hans/ssh:[No such file or directory]
```

In this command, the `.` before `ssh`  disappeared. This problem doesn't occur in the `sh` and `bash` shells. This problem also doesn't happen in the "ksh" shell on Centos.

Is this a bug in the `ksh` shell on Ubuntu?

Comment: Since ksh exhibits the same behavior on my 16.04 I assume it is not a bug otherwise it would have been fixed a long time ago. Seems to be a matter of `../.` because cd-ing to `~/.ssh` works.

Comment: Hmm... this seems to be related to the default `FIGNORE` behavior - see for example [ksh regression: with FIGNORE, . and .. are no longer automatically excluded from glob expansions](https://github.com/att/ast/issues/11)